# Что такое App server необходимый для работы с GCM

Tags: android, сервер

Для отправки push уведомлений используя FCM, необходим app server, я совсем новичок в программировании и всё что я умею, это немного писать на Java и не понимаю концепцию серверов.

Что это за сервер такой, где его надо прописывать, в приложении или это что то, что должно общаться с приложением из вне?
Информации то в интернете много, по тому, что надо прописывать в сервере, но все эти примеры предполагают, что я имею общее представление о том что такое сервер и что он у меня есть.
Так же из того что я читал, следует, что этот сервер нужно писать не на java, а например на php, если это так, то как же я это смогу соединить в моем приложении?

Сам удивляюсь какой глупый вопрос получился, но я даже не его могу сформулировать нормально, так как не понимаю, что же такое этот сервер.

В общем буду признателен, за любую информацию по поводу того, что же такое app server используемый при работе с FCM на android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно поняли что `App server` нужен для того что  бы общаться с приложением из вне. Когда в своем приложении получаете `token` -  вы отправляете его на сервер. Таким образом сервер может по этому токену слать вам `push-notifications`.

Вот пример на `Node js`:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

var API_KEY = "yourApiKey";

var sender = new gcm.Sender(API_KEY);

//объект сообщения 
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'data',
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 1000

    data: {
        message: 'Message from gcm server',
        action: 'Update data on server'
    },

    notification: {
        tag : 'hasData',
        title: "Title text",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        color: "#22C064",
        sound: "notification_sound",
        body: "This is a GCM notification that will be displayed ASAP.",
        click_action: "OPEN_APP" // make intent-filter in Manifest.xml for this action
    }
});



//Список токенов которым будут отправлены сообщения
var registrationTokens = [];

registrationTokens.push('owQMHz9-Ep6FtiB-pp9uFcZTKcdvUhrsG3XdL7IWgZSt8cWfASzPPxEW1cBdLn1OUukqfsk9rlTexO3MQ0EeSdLXaAFXQn7vYzrKG1LTnv8LOxkBQqEd0VnxLd4');


//отправить на конкретные девайсы
sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: registrationTokens }, function (err, response) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    } else{
        console.log(response);
    }
});

//отправить на все устройства которые подписаны на этот топик
sender.send(message, {to : "/topics/global" }, function (err, response) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    } else{
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за ответ! Я правильно понимаю, что то, что вы сейчас написали, это и есть имплементация app server? А отправляются токены из приложения, на сервер GCM?

Comment: Самое главное, что я не могу понять, пишется ли app server в android studio или нет и если нет то где?

Comment: токены отправляются на ваш app server. Здесь просто этого не показано, фактически с приложения нужно слать,к примеру, POST запрос с токеном и сервер его сохраняет, т.е. в строке registrationTokens.push('owQMHz9-) я просто ложу токен вручную, фактически он мог подтянуться с базы данных, а в базу данных он был сохранен в тот момент когда вы с приложения его отправили на сервер.

Comment: Смотря на чем вы его писать будете,  но не думаю что AS подходящий для этого инструмент. Я используя для сервера Node Js пишу его в WebStorm(JetBrains) , Sublime, Atom. Ну это уже дело вкуса, хоть в блокноте.

Comment: Все рано не могу понять, где будет находиться сервер после того как его написать. Но это уже моя проблема, вы хорошо объясняете, просто мне пока сложно все это понять. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Сервер может находиться в каком-нибудь дата-центре или у вас на компьютере. Все зависит от того где вы будете его запускать. Мне для разработки Android  приложения, достаточно запускать его на своем же ноуте, когда приложение уйдет в продакшн то сервер соответственно  тоже нужно будет переместить.

Comment: Стало намного понятнее. Благодарю за "разжеванный" ответ.